# Get the current URL of Cocoa's WebView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview

Im new to Cocoa.

I'm trying to extract the URL of the currently loaded webpage in my WebView object.
I use this WebView to show a login screen and after logging in I have to get some parts of the URL.

I have already tried

```
[[[[frame provisionalDataSource] request] URL] absoluteString];
```

but this one only works one time, when called while loading. If the loading is complete it returns "(null)". The problem is, that it seems like the URL changes while loading the page so i get the wrong URL.

Does anybody know how to get the URL at any time I want?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like the easiest way would be save the URL somewhere else.

Comment: The problem is that i need the URL including a key generated after logging in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Switch `provisionalDataSource` with `dataSource`. Once the frame starts loading, it's not provisional anymore.